# Forcing XCTest to run against one target

Tags: xcode, automated-tests, xctest, xcode-ui-testing, xctestcase

We are using xctests to run end to end ui tests and have a project with a 3 different targets and I don't want UI tests to run on two of them because they are connected to production.

is there anyway to enforce UI tests to run only against one scheme / target ?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. You can set up different test suite by scheme. Click on your scheme in the top let of Xcode, select `Edit Scheme` and then navigate to `Test` in the left side bar of the menu that pops up. From here, you can select to add/remove test targets from the scheme and even enable/disable specific tests.